# как убрать изменения размеров кнопки

Tags: html, bootstrap

Всем привет,

Если открыть http://ec2-34-212-140-26.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/admin/attribute/edit?id=19&page=1 страницу (там логин уже введен)
И навести мышь над кнопками в редакторое - не нашел как убрать изменения размеров кнопки ?

Спасибо!

Comment: Что вам конкретно нужно ? эта кнопка стандартный элемент от Bootstrap-a  опишите суть вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не совсем понятный. Но вангую.
Например, для кнопки SAVE, стили нужно менять в файле style.css, изменения нужно внести в классе .btn-primary:hover

```
.btn-primary:hover{
  border: none;
}
```

Кнопка CANCEL

```
.btn-inverse:hover{
  border: none;
 }
```